# How to make v-for update again after click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, v-for

I'm playing around with vue trying to learn it and I'm having a hard time getting it to run through an array after click.

The array is first empty, but when a button is clicked, this will call a method to populate the array with data. I'm using v-for to run through the array, but it looks like it only runs through the array before the method is called. How can I make it v-for bind after the event?

the method works because it shows the data in the new array in the console.

```
  <button @click="updateList">Update List</button>
  <li v-if="clicked" v-for="item in newList">
    {{ item }}
  </li>

 <script>

 var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     clicked: false,
     list: ["one","two","three"],
     newList: []
   },
   methods: {updateList: function (){
     for (i=0;i<this.newList.length;i++) {
     this.newList[i] = "you are" + this.list[i];
  }
  this.clicked = true;
    }
  }
  })
```

Maybe ignore syntax in snippet above.

Check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/3bgm12dh/1/

Answer (score 2):

`v-if` and `v-for` should be in separate elements. According to Vue official documentation:

> Using v-if and v-for together is not recommended. When used together with v-if, v-for has a higher priority than v-if.

```
<button @click="updateList">Update List</button>

<ul v-if="clicked">
    <li v-for="item in newList">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

For details see [**`v-if` vs `v-for`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for).